# Error AMQ4036 when trying to add a QueueManager to a Cluster in IBM MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to setup a MQ Cluster that has the following config

1. There are 3 host machines, ubuntuvm-1, ubuntuvm-2 and ubuntuvm-3
2. ubuntuvm-1 has one Full repository queue manager and one partial repository queue manager. QM_FR1, QM_PR1
3. ubuntuvm-2 is same as above. QM_FR2, QM_PR2
4. ubuntuvm-3 has only one partial repository queue manager, QM_PR3

Following are the steps I have taken

1. I have created cluster receiver channels on each queue manager that point to its own queue manager.
2. I have created cluster sender channels that point to at least one full repository.
   I have made sure that the channels are correct, i see the tests pass when I run them through the MQ Explorer.

I get an error when using MQ Explorer, I try to add the QM_FR1 queue manger to cluster (CLUSTER1).
Following is the error.

```
Access not permitted. You are not authorized to perform this operation. (AMQ4036)
Severity: 10 (Warning)
Explanation: The queue manager security mechanism has indicated that the userid associated with this request is not authorized to access the object.
```

**Why am I getting this error and how do I fix this?**

Please shout if you want me to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common cause in IBM MQ:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21194313

Answer (score 0):

A little added to the above link, It seems you are using MQ Explorer on "ubuntuvm-1", I wonder, 

  1. which user do u use to start MQ Explorer? 

  2. Does this user in mqm group or  have enough authority to add qmgr to a cluster? 


This piece of error msg said the user you used does not have right to do Qmgr admins work. To further looking at the issue, please show us some output 

  $ id username-who-start MQ Explorer

Qmgr Error log. 

 
 /var/mqm/qmgrs//errors/*.LOG


Another faster way to isolate the issue, you can simply use Terminal to do the procedure; like, 

$ su - mqm 

$ mqsc QmgrNAme

ALTER QMGR REPOS(CLUSTER1) 

 
DEFINE CHANNEL(...... etc

There is no qmgr nor server reboot needed. Hope this help.